# What's the best way to save trivial user states (e.g. dismissed welcome msg) in database?

Tags: mysql, sql-server, database, database-design, data-structures

Should I use (create) a column for every new state? Or one field with a bunch of comma separated states (alternatively a json obj)? Any suggestions welcome.

**UPDATE**

First let me day thanks for the answers. I just want to clear up, what options I see:

1. Put a column for every state in the user row (initial plan) / Can get messy with lots of states (in the future)
2. Put one column with json/xml data in the user row / Easy to maintain (no db change required), but doesn't feel right
3. Have a dedicated states table (thx [lhiles](https://stackoverflow.com/users/751625/lhiles))/ Sounds cool, how would this table look like?

I'm looking for pros/cons of the different implementations. Again: Thanks!

Comment: Could you post a rough structure of what you have in mind?

Answer (score 2):

Create a column for each state. This is proper data normalization.

With a column for each state you can retrieve as few or as many states as needed for the current operation.

All of the states returned will be contained in a single row with each column named. This makes referencing each state value very easy.

It allows you to easily add constraints to each state as needed. (State X can only contain '1' or '2'.)

It allows you to easily query states across users. (How many users have set a state value to 'X'?)

Comment: @Johan: putting all the states into a single column could be denormalization, though.

Comment: Johan: Pick a normalization site, any site. Here's a quote from one: "What is Normalization? Normalization is the process of efficiently organizing data in a database." I'm not suggesting creating extra columns, just creating the proper number of columns. This sure seems like normalization to me.

Answer (score 0):

My preferred method is to create a dedicated table for user settings. Each state/setting corresponds to a column within that table. As your project grows additional columns can be added without cluttering your apps core data.

Another route, if you feel that there will be too many settings to devote 1 setting per column, would be to store the settings as XML (or json as you mentioned) data within SQL. This would allow you to derive any type of state format you wanted, however, it puts more work on the programmer to parse, validate, and persist those settings.

Answer (score 0):

You can save state using an `ENUM` if the states are mutually exclusive; e.g. person is male or female.
Or using a `SET` if states can co-exist; e.g. person is a member of (AA and CA and SOsA*)

A sample table using both:

```
CREATE TABLE test.table1(
  test_enum ENUM('male', 'female') DEFAULT 'male',
  test_set SET('AA', 'CA', 'SOsA') DEFAULT NULL
)
ENGINE = INNODB;
```

If you're using an `ENUM` I personally would recommend you set an explicit default value other than `null`, because most of the time a choice must be made.

Link: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/constraint-enum.html

`*` *(stackoverflow sufferers anonymous)*

Answer (score 0):

I really wouldn't do this with a column per setting, as most of the other people are suggesting.  I'd do a setting per row because this doesn't require schema changes (including upgrade scripts) every time you add a setting.

Better yet, write some reflection code to run on app startup that'll look at the entries on an enum and automatically create a record in the database (with some default value that you specify in a custom attribute on each enum value).

I recently did something like I'm indicating above.  Now to add a new setting, I add an entry to an enum and that's it.  New settings take about 10 seconds.

I may put my code up on CodeProject, it has has made development easy.